# Compiz on XFCE - I can't login now

Tags: compiz, xfce

I have a dual monitor setup. I just got an ATI Raden HD 5450 card.

I was following a tutorial and I ended up opening my XFCE Settings Manager and adding `compiz --replace ccp` as a startup application. I tried rebooting afterwards and all I see is a red screen. I don't even see the login screen.

Can I undo what I just did?

I used my other machine and SSH'd into the problematic one while exporting X and ran the command `xfce4-settings-manager` and removed the `compiz --replace ccp` startup application and rebooted the problematic machine but I still see a red screen.

I've obviously replaced 'something' with Compiz but I'm not entirely sure what the 'something' is. Is it xfce4-wm or something?

**EDIT**
I should mention that when it boots up, once it gets past BIOS and all of that and just when the red screen shows up, a small loading bar appears and once it loads, it's just the blank red screen (i.e. the only difference is the absence of the loading bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a common issue.
I found the solution here: https://mwop.net/blog/2014-11-03-utopic-and-amd.html

Essentially, what I did was, I logged into my problematic machine via SSH and ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'fglrx*'
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
```

I am also running 14.10 but on a 32bit machine, therefore, the following did not work for me:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

However, after running them all and then rebooting the machine via `sudo shutdown now -r`, I was able to login.